# save the size and speed of website

Tags: javascript, html, css, performance, web

I'll work in a project to improve the website. I recommended few best practices for the website like:

- Eliminate render-blocking JavaScript and CSS in above-the-fold
  content
- Enable compression
- Minify JavaScript
- Prioritize visible content
- Optimize images
- Minify CSS
- Minify HTML

All this changes are based in the https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/. But each time I checked the website I had a different score from the same site.

What I would like, is a place (software, add-on or website) to get a score of a live website and save this information to check again after the changes.

Answer (score 1):

http://yslow.org

Does all of this in spades, can be installed as an extension in all major browsers. Source and command line versions are also available.

Comment: How can I save this information?

Comment: Run the command line via node.js. See 
http://yslow.org/node-server/

Answer (score 1):

Use Pingdom Website Speed Test.

It tests everything from performance grade to load time, content types, etc. It's fantastic!

http://tools.pingdom.com/fpt/

Answer (score 0):

- Avoid missing images or files
- Set the right expiration times for each file type
- Minify + Join + Compress CSS & JS
- Use CDN content delivery network on larger sites
- Set JS file/s at the end whenever possible